# How to convert milliseconds to minutes:seconds output?

Tags: python, datetime, time, milliseconds

I want to convert **milliseconds** and have **2:00** output.
It should look like duration of the song.

I was trying with this code:

```
import datetime

seconds = milliseconds/1000
b = int((seconds % 3600)//60)
c = int((seconds % 3600) % 60)
dt = datetime.time(b, c)
print(dt)

>>> 02:30:00
```

Do you have another ideas? Or maybe I should change something in my code.

Edit:
I solved the problem with following code

```
    ms = 194000
    seconds, ms = divmod(ms, 1000)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    print(f'{int(minutes):01d}:{int(seconds):02d}')
```

Comment: Do you care about leftover fractions of a second? You might be looking for the `divmod` function, which combines `//` and `%` into a single step: `divmod(130, 60) == (2, 10)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a simple `divmod`? That way, minutes > 59 are possible and no imports needed, e.g.

```
milliseconds = 86400001 # a day and a millisecond... long song.

seconds, milliseconds = divmod(milliseconds, 1000)
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)

print(f'{int(minutes):02d}:{int(seconds):02d}.{int(milliseconds):03d}')
# 1440:00.001
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=3200))
0:00:03.200000
```

Comment: This is probably the most sensible choice, but doesn't show how to format it!

Answer (score 2):

`b` is minutes and `c` is seconds. But the arguments to `datetime.time()` are `hours, minutes, seconds`. So you're putting the minutes in the `hours` parameter, and seconds in the `minutes` parameter.

Use

```
dt = datetime.time(0, b, c)
print(dt)
>>> 00:02:30
```

If you don't want the initial `00:`, use

```
print(dt.strftime('%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Ah - that gets the other half - realistically, they should specify the arguments `.time(minutes=foo, seconds=bar)` during creation! [class signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using datetime, you're looking for the [`.strftime()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.strftime)!

```py
"%M:%S"  # minutes:seconds
```

You can find a table of format codes here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

However, it's probably easier to just do the math yourself

```py
>>> milliseconds  = 105000
>>> total_seconds = int(milliseconds / 1000)
>>> minutes       = int(total_seconds / 60)
>>> seconds       = int(total_seconds - minutes * 60)
>>> print("{}:{:02}".format(minutes, seconds))
1:45
```